# Custom Segue doesn't animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uicontainerview

I have set up a custom dialog to appear via a custom segue when a button in a container view controller is pressed, the perform function is being called and everything appears to work just fine except for the animation.

Here is the segue on the storyboard:
[image: Here is the segue on the storyboard]

Here is the button:
[image: Here is the button]

Here is the code for the segue:

```
#import "TimerDialogSegue.h"

@implementation TimerDialogSegue

-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
    //Doesn't appear work with the Timer View Controller as the source 
    //  so I use the parent Home View Controller
    UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];
    src = src.parentViewController;

    // set the view frame
    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.height = src.view.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.width = src.view.frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.x = src.view.bounds.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = src.view.bounds.origin.y;
    dst.view.frame = frame;

    // add the view to the hierarchy and bring to front
    [src addChildViewController:dst];
    [src.view addSubview:dst.view];
    [src.view bringSubviewToFront:dst.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
        animations:^
        {
            dst.view.alpha = 1.0f;
        }];
}

@end
```

Here is the code from the Dialog that dismisses it, this part animates just fine

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self dismiss:sender];
}

- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
        animations:^
        {
            self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
            [self removeFromParentViewController];
        }];
}
```

To summarize the Dialog appears and operates correctly the only issue is there is no animation when it appears. It does animate when it disappears. Anyone know how I might fix this or a workaround to animate this Dialog when it appears?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: By the way, I would question what you are doing here. What _are_ you trying to do? This seems like a wrong use of an embedded / child view controller. It looks to me more like an ordinary presented view controller, or even just a view that appears. You could make your life a lot simpler and take much better control over the animation. If you describe the overall effect you're trying to achieve I might be able to show you a better way...!

Comment: The Timer View is toggled by the Clock button at the top so I use the container to isolate layout changes to a single frame and to separate the timer functions from the rest of the code.

Comment: Cool (makes sense for encapsulation) but then why can't it be a presented view controller rather than an embedded view controller?

Comment: The reason I'm pushing this at you is that customizing a presented view controller animation is easy and normal, whereas the need to animate the initial embed is forcing you down this custom segue road, which seem unnecessary.

Comment: well we want it to match our android app and the layout design our designers came up with. As far as I know presented view controllers are their own window right? A whole new view controller would be empty if it was just the timers and we want users to see their timers and grill temperatures at a glance.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to iOS so I'm all ears if there is a better way that fits the layout.

Comment: No, in iOS 7/8 a presented view controller can be over just part of the interface. However if you want the user to be able to interact with the rest of the interface while the timer is present, you are probably doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
    animations:^
    {
        dst.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
```

But `dst.view.alpha` is `1` *already* so nothing happens. You can only animate a *change*.

For example, when you dismiss, you animate this:

```
  self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
```

That works because `self.view.alpha` was `1` so there is actually a change to animate.

Comment: so if I set dst.view.alpha to 0.0f before I call that it should work?

Comment: Try it and see - no need to speculate about what "should work". I guarantee nothing! :) I'm just telling you something obviously flawed in your code, that might be causing the phenomenon.

Comment: Cool - thx for the accept - but let's keep chatting about this architecture (if you like).